# How to replicate virtual box linux server to my own server?

Tags: server, replication, ubuntu-server

I have one virtual box linux server which shows only command prompt... 
And I want to have that server files and Database to my another server...
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

there are several options for start if use the same virtualization technology on the virtual box and the new server you could just create snapshot from your virtual box and than try to run that snapshot on the new server. http://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/CreateSnapshot

The other solution will be to transfer all of your data manually, for that you will need to:

1. Export all your databases the corresponding tools for that type of
   database ( eg. mysqldump for MySQL server )
2. Transfer all files from old to the new server using rsync
3. Install the same software stack / control panels you've had on the virtual box on the new server.
4. Recreate the FTP, MYSQL users and restore files from the transferred data into the same locations as on the virtual box
5. Import the databases from the exported database files using the corresponding tools for that server.

This should do the trick :)